# ReactJS + React Router: How to disable link from React-Router's <Link>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

Using React-Router's Link, I have a set up like so:

```
<Link to={...}>{this.props.live? "Live": "Not Live"}</Link>
```

Where if `this.props.live` gets passed in, I would like to simply display a text "Live" which will direct to a new page. If `this.props.live` is not passed in, want to display the text "Not Live" but remove the hyperlink from it/deactivate/disable it.

Is it possible to do so? I tried `<div style={{pointerEvents: "none"}}>Not Live</div>`, but does not work.

Will be upvoting and accepting answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
let component;

component=this.props.live? <Link to={...}> Live </Link>: <div> Not Live </div>
 render() {
    {component}
  }
```

Cheers:)

Comment: How did I not see that. sigh. Thank you!

Comment: would be better to rename `displayLinkOrNot` to `component`, cos `displayLinkOrNot` is supposed to store a boolean value. bad name choice for variable that actually will contain ui.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.live
? <Link to={...}> Live </Link>
: <div> Not Live </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the page to be redirected using `evt.preventDefault()`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.handleLinkClick = this.handleLinkClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleLinkClick(evt) {
    if (!this.props.live) {
      evt.preventDefault(); // will prevent redirection
    }
  }
  render() {
    <Link onClick={this.handleLinkClick} to={...}>
      {this.props.live? "Live": "Not Live"}
    </Link>
  }
}
```

Shorthand but [controversial](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) version

```
<Link onClick={evt => !this.props.live && evt.preventDefault()} to={...}>
  {this.props.live? "Live": "Not Live"}
</Link>
```

See the [API docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onclicke)